# array combine inputs more then 2

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm working on an implementation of the "Merge Numbers" game, seen here on the Play store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ft.game.puzzle.cubelevels

The idea is that if I have a 2D array of cells, some of which are empty and others of which have numbers, and I place a given number into an empty cell, then if that number matches at least 3 of its neighbors, the neighbors are made empty and the cell value is incremented. A simple example:

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 3 |   | 2 |   |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |   |
|   | 2 | 1 | 4 |
```

If the next number (generated randomly by the game) is 2, and I place it into cell (1, 1) (where (0, 0) is the upper left cell), the new game board should look like this:

```
| 1 |   | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 |   |   |
| 1 |   | 3 |   |
|   | 2 | 1 | 4 |
```

The newly-placed 2 is incremented to 3, and the neighboring cells with value of 2 have been cleared.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this. Here is my code so far:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] w = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 0, 4, 0}, {1, 2, 3, 0}, {0, 2, 1, 4}};
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter space for putting 1: ");
        int a = input.nextInt();
        int b = input.nextInt();

        if (a == 1 && b == 1) {
            w[1][1] = 1;
            for (a = 0; a < w.length; a++) {
                for (b = 0; b < w[0].length; b++) {
                    System.out.print(w[a][b] + " ");

                }
                System.out.print('\n');
            }
            System.out.println("Enter space for putting 4: ");
            a = input.nextInt();
            b = input.nextInt();
            if (a == 1 && b == 3) {
                w[1][3] = 4;
                for (a = 0; a < w.length; a++) {
                    for (b = 0; b < w[0].length; b++) {
                        System.out.print(w[a][b] + " ");

                    }
                    System.out.print('\n');
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I check to see if the neighbors of the newly-added number have the same value?

How can I increment the newly-added number?

Comment: I'm sorry but this question doesn't make any sense to me.  Perhaps you could try rewording it more carefully to make your particular problem more evident?

Comment: This looks like the XY problem to me

Comment: it same with the merge numbers game

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ft.game.puzzle.cubelevels

Comment: I'd recommend you to take a sheet of paper and draw your starting array then what it should look like after you choose to insert arbitrary values. I guess that should be a good start because I don't really understand your question. But as far I know, to access an element on the left: --> array[current_row][current_column - 1], right --> array[current_row][current_column + 1], above -->array[current_row + 1][current_column], below-->array[current_row - 1][current_column]. Beware of the array bounds checking though!